# g.l.b property equal to l.u.b property?

Tags: analysis

So I've been sick and I've missed a couple of lectures of my Analysis class. But I didn't want to be too behind in lecture tomorrow, so I was trying to catch up by reading my textbook and solving some problems.

Here's one I was having some trouble with:

*Prove equivalence between glb and lub property*

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you! :)

Comment: You have defined "$x$ is a lower bound." You need to add a condition that says nothing greater than $x$ is a lower bound. Then a hint for the equivalence, $s\le t$ if and only if $-s\ge -t$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But I'm still having a little difficulty in wrapping my head around what the question is asking itself...

Comment: this might be of use: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308676/proof-of-the-least-upper-bound-or-completeness-axiom-corollary-greatest-lower-b?rq=1

Comment: might also be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65859/greatest-lower-bound-property-and-least-upper-bound-property

Comment: This is a number of years late, but Baby Rudin has a beautiful proof of this in the first chapter.